# Integration of pyspark to other python modules

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, pytest

Is it possible to integrate normal python module with pyspark?

For example if I have two RDDs, comparing and asserting with py.test something like that. I am planning to write data validation tests for Spark application so trying to understand.

I have been using python for a while but Spark is new for me.

Comment: Comparing RDDs doesn't really make sense but otherwise the answer is positive.

Comment: Thanks!. It will be great if you help me with finding some document :)

Comment: It is just a standard Python. There is no special magic here :) If you want some hints how start/stop/reuse SparkContext then PySpark test suites can be a good inspiration.